# error CS0104: 'Vector2' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.Numerics.Vector2' and 'UnityEngine.Vector2'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Help, I am making a game in unity but I get this error, what do I do?

This is my code.

```
using System.Numerics;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject col;
    public Renderer fondo;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 21; i++){
            Instantiate(col,new Vector2(-10 + i,-3),Quaternion.identity);
        }
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {   
        fondo.material.mainTextureOffset += new Vector2(0.02f, 0) * Time.deltaTime;
         
    }
}
```

This is the error.
[image]
what should i do to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

be explicit about which Vector2 you want

```
Instantiate(col,new UnityEngine.Vector2(-10 + i,-3),Quaternion.identity);
```

asujmming that what you want (as opposed to System.Numerics.Vector2)

Comment: Actually rather simply remove the `using System.Numerics;` .. it is nowhere used in the provided code